# Angular NGX Chart not fitting to parent container correctly onload

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a problem. For my angular website I use ngx-charts to draw different kind of charts. The problem is with the pie-chart, because that chart doesn't fit the parent container correctly. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <mat-grid-list cols="10" rowHeight="250px">
        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
            <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>
                        Popular countries
                    </mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                    <ngx-charts-bar-vertical
                        [results]="popularCountriesData"
                        [legend]="false"
                        [showXAxisLabel]="false"
                        [showYAxisLabel]="false"
                        [xAxis]="true"
                        [yAxis]="false"
                        [gradient]="false">
                    </ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>

        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="4" [rowspan]="2">
            <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>
                        Popular hashtags
                    </mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                    <ngx-charts-pie-chart
                        [labels]="true"
                        [results]="popularHashtagsData"
                        [legend]="false"
                        [legendPosition]="legendPosition"
                        [gradient]="false">
                    </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>

        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
            <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
                <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>
                        User accounts
                    </mat-card-title>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
                    <ngx-charts-line-chart
                        [legend]="false"
                        [showXAxisLabel]="false"
                        [showYAxisLabel]="false"
                        [xAxis]="true"
                        [yAxis]="true"
                        [timeline]="false"
                        [results]="accountData">
                    </ngx-charts-line-chart>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>

    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

With the css:

```
.dashboard-card {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.dashboard-card-content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

But this results in:
[image]

As you can see, the pie-chart goes outside the container, while the documentation says:
[image]

The other charts are working perfectly... How can I fix this, wihtout hard coding the sizes in pixels, because it needs to be responsive?

**Edit**
The weird thing is that this problem only occurs on my Dell XPS 13 laptop and not my desktop monitor. So for smaller screens this problem occurs!!!

Comment: Is pie chart being bigger than mat-card the issue? Is it not scaling? Or Chart is not at the center of the mat-card is the issue? I mean from the screenshot, if it shifts towards left then it'll look ok right?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is the pie chart placement. The card around the chart is perfect, because it fits the screen, but I don't know why the chart is places more to the right

Comment: I found something out, with this problem. When I load the page the chart is being placed incorrectly, but when I zoom in/out 1 time, it fits to the frame. Then when I go back to the original zoom, the chart is placed correctly. So if I want it to show correct, I need to zoom first to let the pie chart center...... Any idea, how to get this working onload?

Comment: Try remove or change height: calc(100% - 30px); if the problem persists

Comment: I changed it to: `height: 150px;` to test if something changes, but only the left graph are affected by this change and are getting smaller. Removing doesn't affect the size either. The pie chart is still the same size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try adding the following css to your code.

```
.dashboard-card-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Yesss!!! This fixed it, but could you explain to me why this is working?

Comment: I used `display: flex` and aligned everything in the div to the `center` which you can't do with the `text-align` property. I have edited the `css` to include `box-sizing` so that padding and border will be added to div's total width and height in case you decide to add `padding` to the elements.